# javascript react native expo timer

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and I am using expo to create an app, My app is supposed to subtract a state property every minute once a button has been clicked, the app should continue to subtract the state property even if the app is not open or the phone is sleep, the app seems to work but if my phone goes to sleep the timer stops working  and the state property is no longer being subtracted is there any way I can have the timer keep going and the state property is being subtracted while the phone is sleep or app is not open

```
state = {
bac : 0,
}

componentDidMount(){
this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if(this.state.bac > 0 && this.state.DrinkList.length > 0 && this.state.sessionButtonClicked){
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return{
        bac : (prevState.bac - (this.state.typeNum / 60))
      }
    })
  }
}, 60000)
```